# Modify default workbench view setting at vscode startup

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am attempting to remove Extensions view from vscode Activity Bar, immediately at `code .` start.

Is there a way to toggle it off (change default behavior) at launch?
I don't see that `workbench.view.extensions` is exposed as configurable parameter in `settings.json`.

Another thought I had, was to instead use keybindings for command `workbench.view.extensions`.
But there is "no key" equivalent that responds to starting vscode.

Comment: What do you mean by activity bar? The icons in the sidebar? or the status bar? If you right click on the sidebar icons (activity bar) you can uncheck extensions and the icon is hidden until reactivation

Comment: Yes side bar. I know it can be done manually. I need it done  automatically on launch. (or remove it altogether, if that’s easier)

Comment: That is the `Activity Bar` where those icons live, and when clicked their content is shown in the `Side Bar`.  As @tHeSiD said just hide the extensions icon, that will be remembered between restarts.  Is there some reason that isn't sufficient?

Comment: The objective is to bring 'out of the box' experience. The reason why I look for automated approach on the very 1st start. (I know of Activity Bar icons can be unchecked)

Comment: Were you able to find any command id responsible for hiding the `workbench.view.extensions` extensions? As I understand that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Nope, I gave up trying to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in Visual Studio Code.
From my knowledge, it's impossible to remove or hide the Extensions view from Activity Bar at `code .` start.